# Replacing child of THREE.Group() cause stopping of rotation and translation of a group

Tags: three.js

I created a mesh and added it to a THREE.Group(). Group is rotating and everything is fine, but when I replace Group's child (our mesh) with another mesh, rotation stopped.

Everything is fine here:

```
group = new THREE.Group();
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

group.add(mesh);
scene.add(group);

render() {
   group.rotation.x += 0.1;
}
```

But when I replace the mesh, rotation stops:

```
group.children[0] = mesh2;
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6f5gx02/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly modifying `Object3D.children` is not recommended since this does not update `Object3D.parent` properly. Always use `Object3D.add()` and `Object3D.remove()`. If you write your `replaceWrite()` function like the following, everything works fine:

```
function replaceChild() {

    group.remove( mesh );
    group.add( mesh2 );

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qy1wzf2L/

`three.js R108`